# swift - app purchases

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have questions about making in-app-purchase for iphone.

1. Should I put purchases on the app after a certain level, I'm using a
   SKScene and not a UIViewController, I'm forced to go to a class with
   UIViewController (putting UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,
   SKProductsRequestDelegate) or can I do it directly from SKScene?
2. If I have to pass from a SKScene to viewcontroller, **how do I do it**?
3. If I can do it SKScene, **how do I do it**?
4. Can you tell me a good tutorial to implement the code of purchases in the app?

thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

You implement IAP using StoreKit. The UI is entirely up to you.

There are [many](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation), [many](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) tutorials on adding an IAP to an app. You can also use some open source frameworks to make things easier. I often use [`RMStore`](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore).

Comment: thanks for replying, sorry but I'm a novice. I do not know object-c but only swift. I already use storeKit, but I can not use it with SKScene, I tried to implement UIViewController, but my problem it's present UI from SKScene.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "can not use it with SKScene." StoreKit does not have a user interface. How you implement it is entirely up to you; if you want to use SKScene you can.I'm afraid that we're still at the point with Swift that you need to be able to understand some Objective C even if you don't write it. The reality is that UIKit is ObjC as are most OSS projects.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I thought you could use storeKit only with UIViewControll.
also because I tried to implement it with SKScene but I have never shown the alert for purchase. Now I try again again, thanks.